# eCharts solid-gauge yaxis max float value

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm trying to put a floating point value at the yaxis max of a solid-gauge in HighCharts, but it automatically adds an additional number to the value that I define.

I can't figure out how `tickInterval` works in yAxis.

Comment: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=gauge Solve my problem.

Comment: Is this a Highcharts related question? You are using the demo from ECharts

Comment: Sorry about this, i will use the eCharts. How do i'am delete this question?